# Restrict App Script to the current sheet containing the script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I create an App Script and run it, it asks for permission. However, the permission requested is rather alarming:

[image]

I only need to access the Sheet in which the App Script is located. Is it possible to restrict access to just that? My App Script has no intention to touch any of the user's other data.

My code:

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("My Menu").addItem("Load", "load").addToUi();
}

function load() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  sheet.appendRow(["Hello", "World"]);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you post your code so we can see what might be wrong.  See [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @TheWizEd Added. Just a Hello World write. Code runs fine, and I need it to apply to the sheet containing the script only.